# native android webrtc sdk and android native signalization SDK are used to build Sinch SDK

Tags: sinch

I wouldlike to know witch native android webrtc sdk  and android native signalization SDK are used to build your very simple Sinch Android voice andvideo SDK.

cdt

Answer (score 0):

We constantly update WebRTC and build it, sometimes with slight modifications. The signaling is custom, no standard lib